# Referral Exclusion List Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Does anyone also have this problem?

We use GTM and my settings in GA are correct : all the referrals i don't want are added to the referral exclusion list, still they seem to appear even in the data from yesterday only (and I changed the list 5 days ago), the session expiry setting is at 6hours so it couldn't be cookies either.

If someone knows why this is happening and how to fix this properly I would be glad to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you excluded the main domains or the third levels? In the case, you do not have to exclude the third levels in the referrals exclusion list but the main domains.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably these referrals are just not overwritten by other sources so they are kept with no change as long as visitors would access your site directly. You may try to reset this with shortening the campaign timeout period. 
Here is a [nice overview](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762?hl=en) of how Google Analytics processes source data.

Comment: But my Campaign Timeout is set at 1hour ?